# Foundation top-bar mobile dropdown on top of content not push it down

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm using foundation 5 topbar and trying to make the dropdown menu at mobile level sit on top of the page content rather than push it down.

I've tried setting a  to be relative and then the ul inside it to be position: absolute with a high z-index but it's just not happening for me.

Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: Do you have perhaps have example code or a jsfiddle? And what exactly to you mean with "sit on top of the page". Do you want the topbar to be fixed no matter how far you scroll the page?

Comment: Standard foundation top-bar code that is on their docs page. I just want the mobile size menu to appear over the page content rather than push it down.

Answer (score 0):

It's a know [issue](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/3011), there are no simple foundation solution

Comment: That's not what i'm looking for at all i'm afraid!